# Can I make a methods caller return?

Tags: java

If i have a method a() that call b(x):

```
int d = 0;

void a(){
    int c = b(x);
    d = c;
}

int b(x){
    if(somecondition){
        return x;
    }else{
        retrun null;
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can write the function `b(x)` so that it makes `a()` return before changing `d`, if I don't want to check if `c` is `null` from within `a()`?

Comment: Throw an [Exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html)... but only for "exceptional" situations. AFAIK, it's costly to do and so should not be used for directing program logic.

Comment: To add to Mr. Cleese answer ... http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you use a simple if clause like:

```
int d = 0;

void a(){
    int c = b(x);
    d = (c == null) ? d : c;
}

int b(x){
    if(somecondition){
        return x;
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Warning: `null` is not an `int`.  You'll have to use `Integer` here probably.

Comment: @sled: Because I will need to use this conditional in many times in  many methods like `a()` and it will make the code go ugly, but as explained by Alex there is no (efficient?) way of knowing the caller.

@LouisWasserman: Thank you, right. `a()` and `b()` are provided for illustration. The output of my "real" `a()` is an object that is somethimes `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You could have `b(x)` throw an Exception, that would prevent the assignment to `d`. But then `a()` wouldn't 'return' normally either. Otherwise, there is no way of achieving this without changing the code of `a()`.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can change `a()`'s control flow from `b()` without changing `a()`'s code is throwing an Exception from `b()`. If returning null is an error condition, that may be a good idea.

If null is not an error, there is probably some decision you want to make based on the return value, so checking for null and making the decision explicit is probably your best option.

Answer (score 0):

If the situation is that you're going to be calling b many times in your code and you want to avoid having to rewrite your null check over and over again, then I feel your pain!

If the language supported function pointers, you could try having b accept a function pointer (which would be a), and only execute the function if somecondition were true. Unfortunately, this isn't really an option in Java.

Probably the best is to have b throw an exception, as "Hovercraft Full Of Eels" suggested. If you have your functions re-throw the exception using throws SomeConditionException and catch them all at a higher level, you can avoid some code duplication.